# Fetch URL parameters using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a URL below:-

http://localhost:8080/test/rpw.html?u=64603549618667520&v=7816fb816d1c6bc85b77b372cc5e5eb9

I want to fetch the value of u & v parameter in the controller, How it can be done please give a detailed description with example

Adding the code snippet

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('resetPasswd',['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('passwordCtrl', [$routeParams, function($scope,$routeParams) 
            {
            var params = $routeParams;
            alert("check value   "+params.u);

    }]);
```

Comment: you could try `$location.search()['u']`

Comment: take a look at $routeParams docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: but it is valid for some browsers only, so that won't be the exact solution I think.

Comment: @Jax I am not getting the clear picture how to do it using the $routeParams. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: look at the first comment by @PankajParkar. I would start there.

Comment: @Jax are you using any route engine here like `angular-route` or `ui-router`

Comment: @PankajParkar
I have tried using ,but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Inject '$routeParams' into a controller as such and access the $routeParams object and there you have it.

```
angular.module('app')
      .controller('DummyController', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
                    var params = $routeParams;
                 }
```

The above **$routeParams** gives your controller access to all the parameters in the url in the form of a nice object therefore you are able to access the url parameters very easily. In this case you could do params.u and that would give you your u parameter.

Make sure you injected the ngRoute service into your app beforehand or the above $routeParams won't work.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Reference :

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: I've edited my answer, you need to inject $routeParams with the ''s. So you first need to inject $routeParams just like you would inject any other dependancy into a controller.

Comment: Below code snippet is now working but not giving the value

Comment: var app = angular.module('resetPasswd',['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('passwordCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) 
    {
     var params = $routeParams.params;
     console.log(params);

Comment: could you please check it once

Comment: You haven't injected '$routeParams'... app.controller('passwordCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {.........

Comment: I tried to print the value in console, it is giving the error :- undefined

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're trying to print the params with and also please make sure that the url is set before the controller loads. You aren't doing some sort of location.url are you AFTER the controller has loaded because $routeParams? Either way, $routeParams should not be undefined if you inject it properly and you also inject the ngRoute service to your app.